# unable to capture tooltip message using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

I am facing one issue while capturing the tooltip message of text box using selenium webdriver.This tooltip is being displayed whenever click on text box.it is not being displayed when mouse over on it.The issue here is,it is not identifying the locator of that tooltip while running(i used xpath).Please help on this.

Thanks,
Murali

Comment: Can you show some code + the URL of the web-page you're working on?

Comment: @barak manos: Actually i am trying to automate the Gmail registration page where Gmail address text field is displaying one kind of message when we click on Gmail address text box.I would like to capture that particular message but i am unable to do that.Please help.

Comment: What's the URL, `http://www.gmail.com`?

Comment: @barak Manos: Yes the same URL but in issue in gmail registration page with gmail address text filed

Comment: So the URL is `https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Ftab%3Dwm&ltmpl=default`, and you want to capture the 'You can use letters, numbers, and period' message?

Comment: yes that is the URL..

Comment: And my other question?

Answer (score 0):

first identify the webelement where tool tip is occuring by help of findelement then use getText()

```
  driver.findElement(By.name("xyz")).getText();
```

Comment: first of all,thanks for your help.Actually i am trying to automate the Gmail registration page where Gmail address text field is displaying one kind of message when we click on Gmail address text box.I would like to capture that particular message but i am unable to do that.Even there is no id or title locator exists for that particular message when we spy using firebug.Please help on this.

Comment: also try this--- driver.findElement(By.name("xyz")).getAttribute("value");

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of some sample html code, its hard to know the exact problem. However I would like to share how I tested tooltip in the past. Tooltip is mostly defined by `title` attribute of the html element. So to test tooltip of an element, just grab that element and make sure the title attribute matches the tool tip you expect. Keep your test limited to this only and avoid doing any fancy hover stuff etc.

```
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login_id"));
String tooltip = login.getAttribute("title");
assertThat("Tool tips did not match",tooltip,equalTo("expected tool tip"));
```

Comment: :first of all,thanks for your help.I have tried using above code but no use(Showing errors). Actually i am trying to automate the Gmail registration page where Gmail address text field is displaying one kind of message when we click on Gmail address text box.I would like to capture that particular message but i am unable to do that.Even there is no id or title locator exists for that particular message when we spy using firebug.Please help on this.

Comment: What do you mean by showing errors? Do you mean compilation error? I am sure it must be on `assertThat`, you need static import appropriate  hamcrest `AsserThat`. You don't have to use that, I just wanted to show you how to use the information. Also why are you automating Gmail? Is this developed by your development team?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the username-info message, then use:

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.id("gmail-address-infomessage")).getText();
```

If you want to capture the username-error message, then use:

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.id("errormsg_0_GmailAddress")).getText();
```